# Checking SMTP headers for spoofed email (did client authenticate?)

Tags: smtp, rackspace, spoofing, smtp-headers

I have been using rackspace email service, and I am finding that rogue emails are seemingly coming from `harry@mydomain.com` to `james@mydomain.com` but were never actually sent by that user.

As per rackspace this email was sent via `harry@mydomain.com` using his credentials. From the email headers I cannot tell if this would it be a script running on secureserver.net that is doing this (using his credentials) or is that sending a spoofed email (script is sending SMTP without authentication and just setting the email to/from fields accordingly).

**My questions are:**

1. SMTP servers can receive email in two ways: 1) from other SMTP servers, 2) or from a client that authenticates and relays through it. Without access to the receiving server logs, where is the detail in the header which indicates client is relaying via authenticated username/password?
2. Where the additional details are added, are these spoofed from the sender or genuine: `X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: a2plcpnl0576.prod.iad2.secureserver.net: authenticated_id:admin@weirddomain.com`?
3. Although we have SPF records for the domain to only include the webserver IP and `include:emailsrvr.com` with the `-all` flag, Rackspace say it is not possible to use this to check against spoofed email, or is this because they have authenticated to the SMTP server and relayed in this case?

**Headers are below:**

```
Delivered-To:   james@mydomain.com
Return-Path:    <harry@mydomain.com>
Received:   from smtp48.gate.iad3a (smtp48.gate.iad3a.rsapps.net [172.27.146.93]) by store370a.mail.iad3a (SMTP Server) with ESMTP id 6B21338004D for <james@mydomain.com>; Tue, 22 Mar 2016 18:51:50 -0400 (EDT)
X-Spam-Threshold:   95
X-Spam-Score:   0
X-Spam-Flag:    NO
X-Virus-Scanned:    OK
X-MessageSniffer-Scan-Result:   0
X-MessageSniffer-Rules: 0-0-0-5195-c
X-CMAE-Scan-Result: 0
X-CNFS-Analysis:    v=2.1 cv=Ksx0hwmN c=1 sm=0 tr=0 a=03oFrmF08fajSB7oc4goJw==:117 a=3DDquuGS2V5BkRhJnJP3ow==:17 a=L9H7d07YOLsA:10 a=9cW_t1CCXrUA:10 a=s5jvgZ67dGcA:10 a=AsRiV6KZ74iSbj+k8RJYJIAeGPg=:19 a=2L8f7PMcNrQA:10 a=7OsogOcEt9IA:10 a=KXl77lDgDEgIEtoqJYcA:9 a=_6GpL_ENAAAA:8 a=ZYf_q_66Zn7mdDxIrUkA:9 a=giY71Mj1q15_ivv6:21 a=NF3jo81ehh1LRULu:21 a=wPNLvfGTeEIA:10 a=xupg4knwUDYA:10 a=iDzWDAaf-0_1B4d3PKkA:9 a=AX674DPcPDPt-UkY:21 a=v5bIRgG1RGZFvm2Y:21 a=_W_S_7VecoQA:10
X-Orig-To:  james@mydomain.com
X-Originating-Ip:   [198.71.225.37]
Received:   from [198.71.225.37] ([198.71.225.37:50277] helo=a2nlsmtp01-03.prod.iad2.secureserver.net) by smtp48.gate.iad3a.rsapps.net (envelope-from <harry@mydomain.com>) (ecelerity 2.2.3.49 r(42060/42061)) with ESMTPS (cipher=AES256-SHA) id B2/C7-21891-17EB1F65; Tue, 22 Mar 2016 18:51:50 -0400
Received:   from a2plcpnl0576.prod.iad2.secureserver.net ([198.71.236.72]) by : HOSTING RELAY : with SMTP id iUAOaPfNohy43iUAOaMLT4; Tue, 22 Mar 2016 14:48:44 -0700
Message-ID: <B7.A7.22894.92AA1664@smtp48.gate.iad3a.rsapps.net>
Received:   from [77.234.42.143] (port=65110 helo=[100.100.48.14]) by a2plcpnl0576.prod.iad2.secureserver.net with esmtpsa (TLSv1:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256) (Exim 4.85_1) (envelope-from <harry@mydomain.com>) id 1aiUAO-0010vj-5P for james@mydomain.com; Tue, 22 Mar 2016 14:48:44 -0700
Content-Type:   multipart/alternative; boundary="===============0122389713=="
MIME-Version:   1.0
Subject:    Important
To: Recipients <harry@mydomain.com>
From:   "Harry" <harry@mydomain.com>
Date:   Tue, 22 Mar 2016 16:48:39 -0500
Reply-To:   hitmeup55@hotmail.com
X-Antivirus:    avast! (VPS 160322-0, 03/22/2016), Outbound message
X-Antivirus-Status: Clean
X-AntiAbuse:    This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse:    Primary Hostname - a2plcpnl0576.prod.iad2.secureserver.net
X-AntiAbuse:    Original Domain - mydomain.com
X-AntiAbuse:    Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse:    Sender Address Domain - mydomain.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via:   a2plcpnl0576.prod.iad2.secureserver.net: authenticated_id: admin@weirddomain.com
X-Source:   
X-Source-Args:  
X-Source-Dir:   
X-CMAE-Envelope:        MS4wfEPENpifHOCgRpfP6548FFaFh5aGvLkdZm1fLn1ObUi/GIxIvKJEpHzquISJMsZqy70pnMkKI97Q9A0DqQ32JQ78HW6S1tBah8JgoDrTNI9F4pp4EDOM HTkGtTYtUC9r9UUrKvESTtmSFszS6652/MgX84oIFe88If6ClU4eOj36h5+xgnUIKFWOr106/ju1qIlkFmQeQS7UynivyRiK6r8QHvsju7aabN+eUPHBb+4qI
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key line is here.

```
Received: 
   from [77.234.42.143] (port=65110 helo=[100.100.48.14]) 
   by a2plcpnl0576.prod.iad2.secureserver.net 
   with esmtpsa (TLSv1:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256) (Exim 4.85_1) 
   (envelope-from <harry@mydomain.com>) id 1aiUAO-0010vj-5P 
   for james@mydomain.com; Tue, 22 Mar 2016 14:48:44 -0700
```

It says that `a2plcpnl0576.prod.iad2.secureserver.net` received a message with [SMTP AUTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP_Authentication#Role_in_the_mail_transport_system) abbreviated here as `ESMTPSA` from `[77.234.42.143]` which identified itself as `[100.100.48.14]` (from second-tier non-public IP address space aka [carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)).

`77.234.42.143` resolves to `ten.emfme.net` which should give us actual sender. Since this IP address belongs to AVAST cloud, you may get additional details about messages originating from this IP from `abuse@avast.com`.